# Messages with jQuery in Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

am having troubles with a jQuery message, I downloaded a plugin to make nice alerts in jQuery, it's named Apprise and the messages works fine.

I just have to put this in the head tag:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="../js/apprise.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/apprise.css">
```

Then write apprise() instead of alert() to show the messages, the problem is that I have to call the function apprise() in an Ajax function and this doesn't work.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../includes/register.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(data) {
    apprise('Sucessful');
    location.reload();
  }
});
```

The apprise works if I put it like a return, but don't reload the page.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: This will reload the page , thats why

Comment: You seem to be thinking the call to `apprise()` will block execution, like `alert()` does. That's not the case, custom dialogs are asynchronous, usually take a callback function as an argument, and call that function when they're dismissed. I'd suggest you look for this pattern in your plugin's documentation.